# Make a Ember.js dropdown select an option by default

Tags: ember.js

Below is the snippet defaulting the dropdown with a value.

```js
App.selectedOption.set("option","1");
```

But Don't see the dropdown getting selected with the defaulted value onload.
What could be the issue here?

Snippet for Ember dropdown

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.SortSampleView  }}
      {{view Ember.Select
             contentBinding="App.viewSampleController"
             selectionBinding="App.selectedOption.option"
             optionLabelPath="content.name"
             optionValuePath="content.id" class="dropdown"
         prompt="Select..." }} 
    {{/view}}    
</script>
```

Snippet for selection binding:

```js
App.selectedOption= Ember.Object.create({option:null});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, see [#482](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/482) in the issue tracker. The discussion states that it's not supported to set the selected option by setting the `valuePath` Instead you have to set the specific object as the `selected` one. See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/NgXpF/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{view Ember.Select
             contentBinding="App.viewSampleController"
             selectionBinding="App.selectedOptionController.option"
             optionLabelPath="content.name"
             optionValuePath="content.id" class="dropdown"
         prompt="Select..." }} 
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.viewSampleController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [],
    addObject: function(id, name){
        this.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
            id: id,
            name: name
        }));
    }
});

App.selectedOptionController = Ember.Object.create({
    option: null
});

App.viewSampleController.addObject(1, 'first');
App.viewSampleController.addObject(2, 'second');
App.viewSampleController.addObject(3, 'third');

var second = App.viewSampleController.objectAt(1);
App.selectedOptionController.set('option', second);
```

Comment: Tried Above solution doesn't work! Please suggest how else can we make it to work

Comment: Have you seen the JSFiddle. This works for me. Can you provide a Fiddle with your code which is not working?